# Auto Selection on Eclipse Widget Combo option

Tags: eclipse, widget, swt

I would like to select widget combo first option by default which is in read only mode.Any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` method of `Combo` sets the selected item.

```java
Combo combo = new Combo(parent, SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.DROP_DOWN);

combo.setItems(... items array ....);

// Select first item
combo.select(0);
```

Note that this does not generate a selection changed event. To do that you need to use the `notifyListeners` call:

```java
Event event = new Event();
event.widget = combo;
event.display = combo.getDisplay();
event.type = SWT.Selection;
combo.notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, event);
```

Comment: I am calling same select method with the index of my default value but it's not working .Code is as below :                                                                                                 
 ` if (c instanceof Combo) {
        int dvPos = ((Combo) c).indexOf(defaultValue.toString());
        if (dvPos > -1) {
         ((Combo) c).select(dvPos);
        }
        else {
         //logger
        }`

Comment: select definitely works. Is code actually calling select or is the indexOf failing.

Comment: indexof  returning 0 which is expected index of default value

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you call `select`? This will make that item the selected item, but it will **not** generate a selection changed event.

Comment: yes ,It's displaying as selected item but as per my requirement this selected item should also generate selection event

Comment: It's going in an event loop after calling combo.notifyListeners

Comment: You can't use notifyListeners inside a listener, you will have to delay doing it using `Display.asyncExec` or similar.